# How to convert Date to Other Time Zone in Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am trying to convert Local Date/Time to other Time Zone with JavaScript.

Dates are stored in DB as UTC.

For example,

```
value = "2014-08-15T11:09:10Z"

var dt = new Date(value)
```

the output will be in my Local Timezone

> Fri Aug 15 2014 18:09:10 GMT+0700 (ICT)

But how can I convert this to other Time Zone (i.e - Moscow) by using JavaScript.

Comment: If you're willing to use a library, moment.js will do it for you: see the [docs](http://momentjs.com/timezone/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript

Comment: It seems using library should be a best option.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JS library such as [timezone-js](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js). You could write code like this :

```
 var format = 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss ZZ';
 var dt = new timezoneJS.Date(format , 'Europe/London');
 dt.setTimezone("Asia/Jakarta");
```

you can also check out other `JS library` like:

- [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/)
- [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/)

Answer (score 2):

You may try like this:

```
function myTimeZOne(value, zone) {
    var f = 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss ZZ';
    return moment(value, f).tz(zone).format(f);
}
```

Also check [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)